# Arranging an array of strings (or even a *ptr) alphabetically

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, sorting, alphabetized

So I've read like five or six posts on how to re-arrange arrays, some alphabetically some numerically, and I also read the chapter. This is what I finally came up with,

```
void selectionSort (string array[], int size)
{
int startScan, minIndex;
string minValue;
for(startScan = 0; startScan<(size-1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = array[startScan];
    string temp;
    for(int index = startScan+1; index<size; index++)
    if(array[index] <minValue)
    {
        minValue = array[index];
        minIndex = index;
    }
}
array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
array[startScan] = minValue;
system("pause");
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. It hollers at me about needing to break when I run it. I presume this would work, were it int or any of the number types. Heck, it would probably even run if I had it set up as ASCII values with the char type. But the actual assignment is a string, and I just can't figure it out. I thought about trying to snip out the first letter and convert to char to alphabetize that way, but some of the strings have have the same last name with a different first name, so that wouldn't work either.

What do I need to fix to allow my sort to alphabetize my array?

***UPDATE*** Updated what I had changed in code after reading comments and re-looking back over the book. I no longer get an error when running the code, but it still doesn't sort!

Comment: If by "hollers" you mean it gives you an error, please show that error.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::sort`?

Comment: What you need to do is implement selection sort correctly. Your code is not even close to being a selection sort. Compare the code you wrote to a real selection sort for instance here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: @john Nor any other kind of sort.  (His code is O(n).  If it really did implement a sort, it would be ground breaking.)

Comment: James - Nothing, except I'm not allowed to use it in the assignment. Oh, and I understand the question apparently looked stupid to you but no need to be snarky friend, I'm just trying to learn :(
john - I actually had read that, and I understand the concept (I think) of sorting, I just apparently don't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

So for some reason you choose to not use std, ( you have both swap and sort)

I would like to note your attention to:

```
  temp = array[count];
    array[count]=array[(count+1)]; <-- when count is exactly size -1 you are going to commit overflow to your array
    array[(count+1)] = temp;
```

You need to make sure your indexing does not go over the array bounds..:

```
for(int count = 0; count<size -1 ; count++)
```

(Btw take a look at std::swap, might be nicer for you to use)

Comment: Thanks, I always remind myself to be careful of array boundaries when the assignment uses an array and then I get frustrated with it and forget sometimes. :/ I wish I could use STD swap but the assignment was to modify selectionSort code to sort strings.

Answer (score 1):

There's an obvious out of bounds issue, when you do `array[count
+ 1]` (when `count == size - 1`).  And I don't see how the code
is going to sort anything.  What algorithm are you trying to
use?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you'll get an index out of bounds exception when you reach the end of your array. Since you are accessing count+1, your for loop needs to stop at size-1. This looks like the beginning of a bubble sort, but is incompletely implemented. Do a little research into bubble sort and you should get your answer pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to the fact that I was trying to combine bubble sorting with selection sorting! Admittedly I was also missing a few elements too.